# Is it possible to check the content of Excel/pdf file with the content of HTML file using java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Am new to java. I am in a situation to compare two different files using Java.
Am able to capture the html content in html.txt file and able to download the excel/pdf files through the application. Now, I need to compare or atleast check if the excel/pdf files contains the content in html file. I checked other related questions but they arent helpful.

Please help me on this or suggest any other way.

Comment: If these files are small enough, you could read the files into Strings in memory, and then simply check for excel.contains(html). Is suspect this is not what you are looking for though.

Comment: You meant excel/pdf files you downloaded, the content may contain html instead of the actual xls or pdf?

Comment: Its very easy to search for your question .Try searching it again and show us what you did .

Comment: can you check if changing mime type of excel/pdf link to text/html is allowed in your application or not? then it would be easier to compare htmls..

Comment: Can you provide examples of each of the files, and what you are trying to match against?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but if you mean reading exact contents of the files and comparing them, I think you'll benefit from reading tutorials like this one: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/readers-writers.html.

You need to use java i/o in order to compare the contents of files.

The idea would be:

1. take in the files to be read
2. compare the files to see if one contains the strings of other
3. do something with the information

Comment: I down voted the answer because I feel you posted an answer when you haven't understand the root of the problem.

Comment: Isn't his root problem that he doesn't know the basics of how to utilize the contents of his files?

Comment: That is what I meant. I am asking questions so I can find out the root caused. Currently I don't know :)